# Getting 0 instead of decimal when dividing a int by 100 in SQL

Tags: sql, casting

I have a column Column1 of an `int` type in `myTable` with a value of, let's say, 25.

When inserting `cast(Column1 as decimal)/100` into a temp table `#tempTbl` as following

```
create table #tempTbl
(
   Column1 decimal
)

Insert into #tempTbl
select cast(Column1 as decimal)/100
from myTable
```

I see 0 in the Column1 of a temp table instead of 0.25

When I try `select cast(25 as decimal)/100`, I'm getting 0.25

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the datatype of the target table? There's no precisison for `decimal` and your DBMS might default to no fractional digits, i.e. `decimal(??,0)`

Comment: The datatype of the target temp table was decimal. I changed it to decimal(6,3) and it worked

Comment: `decimal` is no datatype, it needs both *precision and scale*, e.g. in SQL Server the default precision is 18 and the default scale **0**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select cast(Column1 as decimal)/100.0
```

If execute

```
select 25/100.0;
```

It returns

```
(No column name)
0.250000
```

Please see this code.  The decimel length was specified in the DDL of the temp table

```
create table #tempTbl
(
   Column1 decimal(8,2)
)

Insert into #tempTbl
select 25

select Column1/100.0 from #tempTbl;
```

Output

```
0.2500000
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm getting when dividing 25 by 100. However when I'm using the column name instead, I'm getting 0 (Column1/100.0)

Comment: Updated with example where the column1 is decimal(8,2)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select Column1 / 100.0
```

SQL Server does integer division (as you have discovered).  Just including a decimal place in a constant or multiplying by `1.0` usually resolves the issue.

Comment: @gene . . . Are you referring to the query?  Or to the fact that you are inserting a value into a table with a `decimal` column and no defined scale?

Comment: When using a query and inserting a value from the query

Comment: @gene . . . The definition of your column doesn't allow decimal places.  You need to define it correctly.